# How can we use memcache for updated data

Tags: php, caching, memcached

My code is fetching data from data base.It takes around 5 seconds to load data from database.So I used memcached caching for caching database data.so it takes around 1 second for page to load.But the problem is when i update data in database my webpage displays old cached data.so is there any autoupdate mechanism in memcache or how to display often updated data using memcache.
Here is mycode:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect('localhost',portno) or die ("Could not connect");
    $result = $memcache->get('key'. $_SESSION['front_app']['employee_id'].$month.$year); 
        if(!$result){
            foreach ($call_arr as $c) {
                $result[] = $a->get_submitted_status($start_date, $end_date,id); /*this fetches data from database*/
            } 
        } 
        $memcache->set('key'.id.$month.$year,$result);
```

please help in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to auto update mechanism in memcache you can configure expiry period of data item while storing it in memcache server

Please try executing following code snippet

```
$memcache_object = new Memcache();

$memcache_object->connect('localhost', 11211);

$memcache_object->set('key', 'value', MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 30);

echo $memcache_object->get('key');
```

In above code snippet expiry period of value with key stored on memcache server is set to 30 seconds.

Please refer the documentation mentioned in following url.

http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php

Comment: but @rubin  to set new value i need to fetch data from database after expiry period.it will take time to load.

Comment: How do you delete old cache and generate new one when data is changed using memcache ?